# ERROR Error: Cannot find module 'testcafe-hammerhead'

Tags: testing, automated-tests, node-modules, e2e-testing, testcafe

Running TestCafe returns Error: Cannot find module 'testcafe-hammerhead' but testcafe-hammerhead is in the node_modules folder.

Tests running on Jenkins are failing to find node_module testcafe-hammerhead. It seems to be in the node_module folder though. The same tests run successfully locally and were running successfully in Jenkins with no changes. Suddenly they started failing with this issue.

command line in Jenkins:

`node_modules/.bin/testcafe -e chrome:headless new-yorker/auth-subscriber-access-myaccount.js`

package.json:

```
"expect-puppeteer": "^4.1.1",
"google-auth-library": "^3.1.2",
"minimist": "^1.2.0",
"puppeteer-core": "^1.12.2",
"testcafe": "^1.1.4",
"testcafe-browser-provider-browserstack": "^1.1.1-git.201706070945",
"testcafe-reporter-cucumber-json": "^1.2.0",
"testcafe-reporter-json": "^2.1.0",
"testcafe-reporter-spec": "^2.1.1",
"ua-parser-js": "^0.7.18",
"yarn": "^1.15.2"
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the `node_modules` directory and the `package-lock.json` file before installing modules?

Comment: I have and they are running now. thanks! now i have to figure out why Jenkins doesn't recognize Browserstack that is installed through package.json.